# Spivak's Calculus, Ch. 11, **68: $f(x)=\alpha x+x^2\sin{1/x}$ for $x \neq 0$, $f(0)=0$. Prove $f$ is not increasing in an interval around $0$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, proof-explanation

Two asterisks on a problem in Spivak's Calculus signal a potentially very tricky problem. I solved the following two asterisk problem from chapter 11, "Significance of the Derivative". I am wondering about the correctness of the steps to solve item c and d.

This will be a long question, hopefully someone has patience :).

> **68. Let $f(x)=\alpha x+x^2\sin{1/x}$ for $x \neq 0$, and let $f(0)=0$. In order to find the sign of $f'(x)$ when $\alpha \geq 1$ it is
> necessary to decide if $2x\sin{1/x}-\cos{1/x}$ is $<-1$ for any
> numbers $x$ close to $0$. It is a little more convenient to consider
> the function $g(y)=\frac{2\sin{y}}{y}-\cos{y}$ for $y \neq 0$; we want
> to know if $g(y)<-1$ for large $y$. This question is quite delicate;
> the most significant part of $g(y)$ is $-\cos{y}$, which does reach
> the value $-1$, but this happens only when $\sin{y}=0$, and it is not
> at all clear whether $g$ itself can have values $<-1$. The obvious
> approach to this problem is to find the local minimum values of $g$.
> Unfortunately, it is impossible to solve the equation $g'(y)=0$
> explicitly, so more ingenuity is required.
>
> (a) Show that if $g'(y)=0$, then
>
> $$\cos{(y)}=\sin{(y)}\frac{2-y^2}{2y}$$
>
> and conclude that
>
> $$g(y)=\sin{(y)}\frac{2+y^2}{2y}$$
>
> (b) Now show that if $g'(y)=0$, then
>
> $$\sin^2{(y)}=\frac{4y^2}{4+y^4}$$
>
> and conclude that
>
> $$|g(y)|=\frac{2+y^2}{\sqrt{4+y^4}}$$
>
> (c) Using the fact that $\frac{2+y^2}{\sqrt{4+y^4}}>1$, show that if
> $\alpha=1$, then $f$ is not increasing in an interval around $0$.
>
> (d) Using the fact that $\lim\limits_{y \to \infty}
>  \frac{2+y^2}{\sqrt{4+y^4}}=1$, show that if $\alpha>1$, then $f$ is
> increasing in some interval around $0$.

**Here is my solution**

**a)**

We know that $$g(y)=\frac{2\sin{y}}{y}-\cos{(y)}, \text{ for } y \neq 0\tag{1}$$

$$g(y)=$$

$$g'(y)=\frac{2\cos{y}\cdot y -2\sin{y}}{y^2}+\sin{y}=0$$

$$\implies \cos{(y)}=\sin{(y)}\frac{2-y^2}{2y}\tag{2}$$

Now we substitute this back into $(1)$ to obtain

$$g(y)=\sin{(y)}\frac{2+y^2}{2y}$$

**b)**

Starting from $(2)$, we square both sides to obtain

$$\sin^2{(y)}=\frac{4y^2}{4+y^4}\tag{3}$$

Then

$$|g(y)|=\left | \sin{(y)}\frac{2+y^2}{2y} \right |=|\sin{(y)}| \left | \frac{2+y^2}{2y} \right |$$

And after we sub in $(3)$ we obtain

$$\implies |g(y)|=\frac{2+y^2}{\sqrt{4+y^4}}$$

**c)**
**My question is about this part.**

The problem statement claims that $\frac{2+y^2}{\sqrt{4+y^4}}>1$.

Proof

$$|2+y^2|=2+y^2= \sqrt{(2+y^2)^2}$$

$$=\sqrt{4+4y^2+y^4}>\sqrt{4+y^2}, \text{ for } y \neq 0$$

$$\implies \frac{2+y^2}{\sqrt{4+y^2}}>1$$

$$\blacksquare$$

Assume $\alpha=1$.

$$x \neq 0 \implies f(x)=x+x^2\sin{(1/x)}$$
$$f'(x)=1+2x\sin{(1/x)}-\cos{(1/x)}$$
$$=1+g(1/x)$$

Since we know that $f'>0$ for some point in any interval around $0$ (we can conclude this based on a previous problem), if we can show that $f'<0$ for some point in any interval around $0$ then we will have shown that $f$ is not increasing in any interval around $0$.

Let $y=-2\pi k, k=1,2,...$.

Then $g(-2\pi k)=-\cos{(2\pi k)}=-1$.

Recall that $g'(y)=\frac{2\cos{y}\cdot y -2\sin{y}}{y^2}+\sin{y}$. Therefore

$$g'(-2\pi k)=-\frac{1}{\pi k}<0$$

Hence there is some $c \in (-2\pi k-\delta, -2\pi k) \land g(y)<g(-2\pi k)=-1$

Finally, this means that

$$\exists c, c \in (-\frac{1}{2 \pi k}, -\frac{1}{2\pi k+\delta}) \land g(1/x)<-1$$

Hence $f'(c)<-1$.

**d)**

$\lim\limits_{y \to \infty} \frac{2+y^2}{\sqrt{4+y^4}}=1$ means

$$\forall \epsilon>0\ \exists N>0\ \forall y\ y>N\implies \left | \frac{2+y^2}{\sqrt{4+y^4}} -1\right | < \epsilon$$

$$\implies 1-\epsilon<|g(y)|<1+\epsilon$$

Assume $\alpha>1$.

$$x \neq 0 \implies f(x)=\alpha x+x^2\sin{(1/x)}$$

$$f'(x)=\alpha+2x\sin{(1/x)}-\cos{(1/x)}$$
$$=\alpha+g(1/x)>\alpha-|g(1/x)|$$

Let $\epsilon=\frac{\alpha-1}{2}$.

Then

$$1-\frac{\alpha-1}{2}<|g(1/x)|<1+\frac{\alpha-1}{2}$$

$$\frac{3-\alpha}{2}<|g(1/x)|<\frac{1+\alpha}{2}$$

Therefore

$$f'(x)>\alpha-\frac{1+\alpha}{2}=\frac{\alpha-1}{2}>0$$

That is

$$\exists N>0\ \forall y\ y>N \implies f'(x)>0$$

$$\exists N>0\ \forall x\ x<\frac{1}{N} \implies f'(x)>0$$

Therefore, $f$ is increasing on $(0, \frac{1}{N})$.

Similarly, because $\lim\limits_{y \to -\infty} \frac{2+y^2}{\sqrt{4+y^4}}=1$ we can show with very similar steps that

$$\exists N<0\ \forall x\ x>\frac{1}{N} \implies f'(x)>0$$

Also, $f'(0)=\alpha$, so we can say that

$$\exists N>0\ \forall x\ |x|<\frac{1}{N} \implies f'(x)>0$$

Therefore $f$ is increasing on $(-\frac{1}{N}, \frac{1}{N})$.

Comment: There mus te a typo on sub-question (d).

Comment: @ChoripánConPebre I've corrected the typos.